# Mobile first Custom Login Module adapter deployment failed Bluemix mfp Container

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Hi I am trying to deploy the Custom Login application give in
Github
to Bluemix I deployed the .wlapp to the container. But I could not deploy the AuthAdapter provided. It is failing to get deployed.

Keeping that aside I tried to deploy the starter application provided in the 
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/sample-app/
It is giving [Error shown is as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY8hy.png)
The request is coming to my localhost mobilefirst server
What should I do to solve this problem and get the apps deployed on bluemix mfp container
How to deploy custom auth adapters which is not getting deployed to Bluemix

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention if you are using the pre-configured evaluation container, or your own container.

- Pre-configured:  https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/evaluate/
- Your own container:  https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/run/

You can't open a question and say "deployment fails". It's not going to help anyone solve your problem. **mention the error you're getting during the deployment attempt**.

An "auth adapter" implies it is using some security test(s). If your server on Bluemix (see "your own container") was not configured correctly with said security test(s) in its authenticationConfig.xml file, this could fail an adapter deployment.

The screen shot in your question clearly shows a CORS issue. Chrome does not allow CORS (attempting to get data for different domains).

Make sure that your application points to the correct server - not your local host one, since you want to use your Bluemix server, right? So in its worklight.plist file or wlclient.properties file, make sure the wlHost property is pointing to the correct server.